# Property list value constraints in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, types, plist, constraints

I would like to constraint the values you can give to an item in one of my plist files. For example the built in info.plist uses this feature:

[image: plist item has constraints]

Here you can only select these four values. I would like to make an item, where only my custom values can be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature of Info.plist. You can put any values you want in Info.plist; they just won't be interpreted correctly. The feature you're looking at is a feature of the Info.plist editor in Xcode. It just shows you values it believes are legal; it's even been wrong in the past, and you had to manually add entries it doesn't know about. It's not a general plist feature. You could only implement it by creating your own plist editor.

Comment: That would be an entire app. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It would have been just a minor convenience feature, so it's not that important. But thank you for clarification.